# OpenOffice always print a copy for every page

Tags: 10.10, openoffice.org, printing

Openoffice in 10.10 always send a extra copy for each page in my document's (writer, calc) on a HP Laserjet 4250 and HP Deskjet 3920.

I double check "Copies" option and is set to 1, but always send a extra copy.

Comment: I see the same thing in 12.04

Comment: This question was posted some time ago. In case it is not yet solved: try to narrow down the problem. I hope some of these ideas help: When you invoke Print (via File > Print...), the dialog window shows the number of pages to be printed at the lower-left corner. Is it showing the correct number of pages, or is it showing duplicates? Have you tried Exporting to PDF (File > Export to PDF) and then printing the resulting file? Does this also result in an extra copy being printed? Have you tried another printer? regards -Ricardo

Comment: This issue, if still persistent, should be reported to the openoffice support, to allow developers to know about it, thus fixing it.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).